# \thepage cannot refer the roman page number

Tags: numbering, conditionals

I want to write 'A' in odd page number and 'B' in even page number. This code below only apply for arabic page number, but the roman page number can't. How to write 'A' in odd page number and 'B' in even page number for roman page?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\backgroundsetup%
{   angle=0,
    opacity=1,
    scale=1,
    color=black,
    contents=%
    {
        \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{%
            {\Huge A}
        }{
            {\Huge B}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{PREFACE}
    \newpage
    \chapter{ABC}
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{TEST1}
    \newpage
    \chapter{TEST2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\thepage` is the print form so `i` for roman which is not odd, use `\value{page}` which is the underlying number in the count register.

Comment: Thank you very much @David Carlisle, the code is work for the roman page number.